# Operator * cannot be applied to double

Tags: java, android, operator-keyword, multiplication

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bereken:

           EditText basis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Basis);
              String tussenBasis = basis.getText().toString();
                Double.valueOf(tussenBasis);
            //

            EditText hoogte = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Hoogte);
              String tussenHoogte = hoogte.getText().toString();
                Double.valueOf(tussenHoogte);

            double half = 1 / 2;
            //half = 0,5

            double einde = half * basis * hoogte;
            //eind antwoord formule

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.antwoord)).setText("Het antwoord is: " + einde);
            break;
    }

     }
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple calculator for the area of a triangle, but I seem to be stuck here.

Comment: Read the *full* error message and note *all/both* types. Why don't they "play well together" with multiplication?

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title.  The Stack Overflow way of indicating this is by clicking the "tick" icon next to the answer that resolved the issue for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`half * basis` is illegal as `basis` is of type `EditText` (and so is `hoogte`) What are you trying to multiply `half` by? Maybe you need to assign the results of `Double.valueOf(tussenBasis)` and `Double.valueOf(tussenHoogte)` to a `double` variable and use that in your multiplication?

```
EditText basis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Basis);
String tussenBasis = basis.getText().toString();
double basisDouble = Double.valueOf(tussenBasis);
//

EditText hoogte = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Hoogte);
String tussenHoogte = hoogte.getText().toString();
double hoogteDouble = Double.valueOf(tussenHoogte);

double half = 1d / 2d;
//half = 0,5

double einde = half * basisDouble * hoogteDouble;
```

Also note the change from `double half = 1 / 2;` to `double half = 1d / 2d;`

(edit in response to comment from OP) You need to use a "type suffix" of `d` to specify that your literals (the characters `1` and `2`) are [double literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) (see the [Floating Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) section of "The Java Tutorials > Primitive Data Types" for a more plain English explanation).

Without this they are interpreted as integer literals. An arithmetic operator with two integer variables causes then integer division is performed (due to [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) treating them both as integers). That gives the result (as an integer number) of `0`. Only then is the result widened (using [widening primitive converstion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) to a double during the [assignment conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

Comment: I understand it would otherwise result to zero, hence you added the "d"s but what do they stand for?

Comment: @MalumAtire832 see my edit explaining why you need them. In general, specify numbers being assigned to `float` with the type suffix `f`, to `double` with `d` and to `long` with `L`. You don't need a suffix for an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText basis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Basis);
```

Is not a value you can use in arithmetic. Same with:

```
EditText hoogte = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Hoogte);
```

You are trying to use them here`double einde = half * basis * hoogte;`

Which cant be done.

I am pretty sure what you need is to save these values to a variable

```
Double.valueOf(tussenHoogte);
Double.valueOf(tussenBasis);
```

and then use those variables in your arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

You have * hoogtie  and basis which are `EditText` and can't be multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Double.valueOf`, you need to assign the result to something.  So like this.

```
EditText basis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Basis);
String tussenBasis = basis.getText().toString();
double basisValue = Double.valueOf(tussenBasis);
```

and similarly with the `hoogte`.  Then you can write

```
double einde = half * basisValue * hoogteValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are extracting the value from the `EditText`, but you aren't using the `double` value you are parsing in this line, for example:

```
Double.valueOf(tussenBasis);
```

You are attempting to use the `EditText` itself as a factor, but it's not a `double`, so it can't be used with the `*` operator to multiply the values.

Assign the results of `Double.valueOf` to new `double` variables, and use those variables in your calculation.

Incidentally, `1 / 2` is integer division in Java and will evaluate to `0`.  Try `1.0/2.0` or just use `0.5`.